# React new HOOKS api, useReducer with dynamic initialState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In case we want to fetch data from remote server and then pass it as initial state to a reducer, how we can proceed ? I tried to call dispatch inside useEffect but it was rejected as per rule of calling hooks inside useEffect(...) is forbidden﻿,

Any help ?

Comment: It will be difficult to get it to the initial state passed to `useReducer`, put you could have an action that sets the initial data after the request is complete.

Comment: This has nothing to do with hooks and hooks can't solve that problem either. This has also always been the case with class based components that fetch initial data. You either need to define an empty initial state and render e.g. a loading indicator or do the fetch in the parent and only render the component when the initial state is ready. Hooks can't help you get around that. Also [`Suspense`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense) may help you with that.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to call `dispatch` from within `useEffect`, you just can't call `useReducer` (or other hooks) from `useEffect` (which means as the others indicated that the initial state will just need to be some unused value such as null, undefined, {} and then replaced once you have the real value). The `dispatch` function returned by `useReducer` is not a hook. Please show the code of how you tried to do this.

Comment: Sorry, somewhere in my code, I am calling useContext ,

Answer (score 7):

The only way you can pass the data as the initial state to a reducer is to fetch the data before rendering your component. You can do that in the parent:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall().then(response => {
      setData(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  if (!data) return null
  return <MyComponent data={data} />
}

const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, data)
  ... // utilize state
}
```

.

The above approach is undesirable as it breaks separation of concerns. Usually it is better to set a null initial state and call `dispatch` to change it to the desired state:

```
const MyComponent () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, null)

  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall().then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'INITIALIZE',
        data: response.data
      })
    })
  }, [])

  if (!state) return null
  ... // utilize state
}
```

.

Comment: Thanks Jemi, do you know if there's some other way to set initial state dynamically without having to use useEffect?

Comment: @Operator, setting the initial state dynamically is not an issue, just pass the initialization function as a parameter to `useReducer` as explained in the api reference https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#specifying-the-initial-state. `useReducer(reducer, null, initializationFn)`.

OPs example is more complex because he needed to use the return value of an asynchronous function to intialize the state. The asynchrony led to the wonkier solution I wrote up.